# Google app engine error 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Hi I am running google app engine which has randomly stopped working here are the logs. I am not a coder but wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction as to what is wrong?

```
I2015-04-29 15:54:13.305 / XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 500 7ms 2kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=1
0.1.0.2 - - [29/Apr/2015:07:54:13 -0700] "POST /solvehook HTTP/1.1" 500 2352 "https:// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" " XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com" ms=7 cpu_ms=9 cpm_usd=0.000263 queue_name= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX task_name=4598293485967329217 app_engine_release=1.9.19 instance=00c61b117c99323f8203eca8b1aa54c6e0d29e
I2015-04-29 15:54:13.302 start of: activities_update
I2015-04-29 15:54:13.302 followupid: 141775527, contactid: 141774193
I2015-04-29 15:54:13.303 details already set: Make Reservation
I2015-04-29 15:54:13.303 Contact categorise (Pending Reservation: 98837900
E2015-04-29 15:54:13.303
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
       rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
       rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
       return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
       return handler.dispatch()
     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
       return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
       return method(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /1.375951812156871492/endpoint2.py", line 79, in post
        'activities.create' : activities_create}[notification.find('type').text](postdata,notification)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /1.375951812156871492/endpoint2.py", line 171, in activities_update
        add_pending_reservation_category(postdata,notification)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/1.375951812156871492/endpoint2.py", line 331, in add_pending_reservation_category
       logging.info('Contact categorise (Pending Reservation: ' + categoryid) + ')'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Looks like a syntax error to me (and possibly a None categoryid?): logging.info('Contact categorise (Pending Reservation: ' + categoryid) + ')'. Not easy to tell without the code...

Comment: `logging.info` is what's returning `None`, just removing the last 6 characters ` + ')' ` should be enough to avoid this error; I think it has always been that way so this code should've always failed, if this started happening recently then maybe something else is making the app take this code path.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will remove the code tomorrow and try it and let you know